# How to hide more videos (Video suggestions) in youtube player api android

Tags: android, youtube-api

i am using youtube player api in android. How to hide more videos(Video Suggestions) from the player.

Comment: can you add code? What you had tried

Comment: @Harish Penta did you find the solution for this ???

Answer (score 3):

I tried to look for the same solution but couldn't find any.
So found a workaround which will reset the video after it is finished.

inside your onInitializationSuccess method implement PlayerStateChangeListener and inside onVideoEnded method reset the player to bring the video at the start and pause it. (below is my implementation in Kotlin language).
Hope anyone looking will find it useful.

```
override fun onInitializationSuccess(
            p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
            p1: YouTubePlayer?,
            p2: Boolean) {
            p1!!.loadVideo(videolink)
            p1.setPlayerStateChangeListener(object:YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener{
                override fun onLoading() {}
                override fun onLoaded(p0: String?) {}
                override fun onAdStarted() {}
                override fun onVideoStarted() {}
                override fun onVideoEnded() {
                    p1.seekToMillis(0)
                    p1.pause()
                }
                override fun onError(p0: YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason?) {}

            })
        }
```

Comment: This is a really good answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Though YoutubeVideoPlayer doesn't allow to disable videos recommendation, but i've found a better work around based on @Ravi_Dudi's solution `onVideoEnded` callback, /
instead of

```
youTubePlayer.seekToMillis(0);
youTubePlayer.pause()
```

use

```
youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoID);
```

where `videoID` is previously played videoId.
Here is complete code for better understanding:

```
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(getResources().getString(R.string.developer_key), new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer,
                                            boolean wasRestored) {


            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
            youTubePlayer.setFullscreen(true);

            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoID);

            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoading() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoaded(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAdStarted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onVideoStarted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onVideoEnded() {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoID);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
            //print or show error if initialization failed
            Log.e(TAG, "Youtube Player View initialization failed");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters

> After... September 25, 2018 ... you will not be able to disable
>   related videos. Instead, if the rel parameter is set to 0, related
>   videos will come from the same channel as the video that was just
>   played.

Comment: I think question was about Android Player API, you gave the solution of Web.

Comment: Is there a solution for android player api?